# Microprint in LaTeX?

Tags: fontsize

Is there a package for microprint? What I mean by microprint is text that is so small that, unless a trained eye actively searches for it, it just appears as a solid line. I first became aware of it on recent US currency: http://www.newmoney.gov/newmoney/images/features/thumbnails/micro_10_sm_new.jpg

I initially thought the `microtype` package would help this, but this is something wholly different. I would love some suggestions!

I see that the `memoir` class has has a `\miniscule` option, but is it possible to do something like this in the `report` class?

Comment: `\scalebox{0.01}{hello}` change `0.01` to whatever you want

Comment: What @David says. Another option is `\fontsize{0.1}{0.1}USA 100 USA 100 USA`. If you don't give us more details on what do you want, I'm afraid we can't be more specific...

Comment: @tohecz: I agree with you, the post is somewhat unclear... Regarding the linked image, I believe that the OP just wants tinyyyyyyyyyy fonts ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But maybe also text along path, who knows... Both things have an answer somewhere on the site.

Comment: I forget that so often with LaTeX the question isn't "can I do this" but rather "how specific can I get with this". I have no specific intentions, I just wanted to know how to get exceedingly small fonts, which you all answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the `scalebox{}` command of `graphicx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\scalebox{0.1}{Hello World}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what David suggested in his comment ;) but it's not clear whether this is what the OP actually asks.